# How to prevent race condition with INSERT?

Tags: mysql, sql, pdo, innodb, race-condition

How would i go about preventing race conditions when INSERTing a row into a table that contains no unique index. For example say my table is....

```
key | slot | label
------------------
 1  |  1   | some
 1  |  2   | some
 2  |  1   | some
 2  |  2   | some
```

... is the only way to prevent such race conditions to create a composite unique field such as "key:slot" e.g.

```
id  | key | slot | label
------------------------
1:1 |  1  |  1   | some
1:2 |  1  |  2   | some
2:1 |  2  |  1   | some
2:2 |  2  |  2   | some
```

...or is there a more efficient way that has escaped me? What about if i was to check for duplicate rows after the insert has been performed and roll the transaction back if there are any found?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

actually you can do it without the `key:slot` column. You can define a unique compound key on the table. eg,

```
ALTER TABLE tableName ADD CONTRAINT tb_uq UNIQUE (`key`, slot)
```

Comment: Excellent, i wasn't aware that was possible but looks like the ideal solution, thanks :)

Comment: Quick follow up, i previously had a non unique index on 'key' which i presume is no longer of use?

Comment: it will still be used for searching `:D`

Comment: Got you, so the constraint is, well a constraint and not an actual search index. Thanks again :)

Comment: The index on `key` alone is not necessary if you have an index on `(key, slot)` since it is usable for searching. However if you had an index on just `slot` you should keep that, since it's not a prefix of your new index.

Answer (score 1):

How about using [LOCK TABLES](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/lock-tables.html) syntax to prevent race conditions when inserting?

Comment: My concern with locking the full table is that the table in question will be heavily read from and i'm not sure how much this would affect performance?